# Bouncing ball stops bouncing?

Tags: game-physics, processing.js

I could not find how to ask so there is a demo at the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetatas/jvH6k/6/). I am pretty sure this is a simple question but I can not seem to find why.

My question is: Why the ball stops bouncing? Is it about something like rounding in multiplications or divisions etc...

```
   void move() {
        PVector v0 = v;
        PVector dv = PVector.mult(a, deltaT);
        v.add(dv);

        PVector d = PVector.add(
            PVector.mult(v0, deltaT),
            PVector.mult(dv, deltaT * 0.5));

        move(d.x, d.y);
    }


    void move(float dx, float dy) {
        p.x += dx;
        p.y += dy;

        if (p.x > width - r) {
            p.x = width - r;
            v.x = -v.x;
        }
        if (p.x < r) {
            p.x = r;
            v.x = -v.x;
        }
        if (p.y > height - r) {
            p.y = height - r;
            v.y = -v.y;
        }
        if (p.y < r) {
            p.y = r;
            v.y = -v.y;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue with this part of the code:

```
if (p.y > height - r) {
   p.y = height - r;
   v.y = -v.y;
}
```

Imagine that height is 600 and r is 10. When the ball hits the bottom (*p.y > (600 - 10)*) it gets reset to  *(600-10)*. But the ball can hit the bottom below that: p.y can be *higher* than height, leading to the issue you're having. The correct code in this case would then be:

```
if (p.y > height - r) {
   p.y = (p.y - height) + (height - r);
   v.y = -v.y;
}
```

Being *(p.y - height)* what you're losing each time the ball bounces.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a multiplication by a variable that is < 0 in every **Move** of **Ball** object. 
Its the PVector a; of Ball object which initially gets the value of gravity (*PVector gravity = new PVector(0, 0.0025);*) 
in the setup()

```
ball.a = gravity;
```

Then in every **Move**

```
 PVector dv = PVector.mult(a, deltaT);
```

Eventually this leads to a PVector dv value of zero.

if you change the

```
PVector gravity = new PVector(0, 0.0025);
```

to

```
PVector gravity = new PVector(0, 0.025);
```

you will see a stronger effect of gravity.

Comment: 0.0025 is not `< 0` and `PVector.mult(a, deltaT)` creates the same `dv` value which is `> 0`, in every move. So I do not think that this is the reason (Or I did not understand you correctly :). Even increasing gravity just makes same thing happen faster.